# Allow user role "salesman" to view only "client" role users

Tags: user-roles, wpdb

I have created two new roles in my theme, salesman and client.
I want, when "salesman" is logged in to be able to view and edit only "client" users.
I am trying this code (taken from an answer in this site)

```
add_action('pre_user_query','yoursite_pre_user_query');
function yoursite_pre_user_query($user_search) {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();

  if ($user->has_cap('salesman')) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_search->query_where = str_replace(
        'WHERE 1=1',
      "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID=6",$user_search->query_where);
  }
}
```

but actually, I can only filter (ID=6) using the ID of user.
I want to change the code and make it like

```
  "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.role='client'" <-----
```

but it doesnt work of course. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Tried `user_role` instead?